# How to count all row occurrences of query results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, rowcount

I am not sure if I am doing this wrong or not including something I should be, but I am using `rowCount()` to try and count all the rows in my database for the query results, like this: `$count_total_friend = $friend_stmt->rowCount();`. The results are showing 6 when it should be only 2. It seems as if it is counting all the rows in my database, rather than my queried results.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

The

```
    $friend_status = 2;
    $friend_sql = "
        SELECT *
        FROM friends
        WHERE friend_one or friend_two = ?
        AND status = ?
    ";
    $friend_stmt = $con->prepare($friend_sql);
    $friend_stmt->execute(array($user_id, $friend_status));
    $friend_total_rows = $friend_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $count_total_friend = $friend_stmt->rowCount();
    foreach ($friend_total_rows as $friend_total_row) {
        //$select_friend_1  = $friend_total_row['friend_one'];
        //$select_friend_2  = $friend_total_row['friend_two'];
        //$friend_status        = $friend_total_row['status'];
        //$friend_status_date = $friend_total_row['date'];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your query

```
    SELECT *
    FROM friends
    WHERE friend_one or friend_two = ?
    AND status = ?
```

It should be something like

```
    SELECT *
    FROM friends
    WHERE (friend_one = ? or friend_two = ?)
    AND status = ?
```

Of course you will need to bind the right params

Comment: It still shows 4 if I do that. The params would be `WHERE friend_one = 24 or friend_two = 24
    AND status = 2`

Comment: Just caught that. Thanks for the help!\